# Parametrized trait with its self type

Tags: scala, polymorphism, traits

I have class with couple of mixins TraitA and TraitB.

```
class ClassA 
trait TraitA[L]
trait TraitB[L]{
 self: ClassA with TraitA[L] =>
}
class ClassB[L] extends ClassA with TraitA[L] with TraitB[L]
```

Is there any way not to point out a type in TraitA, because it seems like it have enough information about type in line `self: ClassA with TraitB[L] =>`
to have something like that

```
class ClassA 
trait TraitA[L]
trait TraitB{
 self: ClassA with TraitA[L] =>
}
class ClassB[L] extends ClassA with TraitA[L] with TraitB
```

I can do the following

```
class ClassA 
trait TraitA[L]
trait TraitB{
 self: ClassA with TraitA[_] =>
}
class ClassB[L] extends ClassA with TraitA[L] with TraitB
```

but in that case I am losing the type of TraitA inside TraitB

Comment: None of your code seems to compile.

Comment: @pedrofurla thanks, fixed

Comment: I think `with TraitB[L]` in your first example is redundant. I guess I am agreeing with @jwvh.

Comment: Your code example doesn't seem to match the `TypeA` and `TypeB` names in the second paragraph; is it possible that they need to be updated? Do you mean that you would like to omit the type parameter for `TraitB`, but still be able to access it?

Comment: @devkat exactly! I want to omit the type parameter for TraitB in definition of ClassB because it seems to be redundant.